# Trying to open spark after installation and getting an error: Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8"

Tags: java, macos, scala, apache-spark, homebrew-cask

**Description:**

I installed spark on my MacBook following using *Homebrew*. I followed the instruction process from: https://www.tutorialkart.com/apache-spark/how-to-install-spark-on-mac-os/.

The step by step process included installing Java, followed by Scala and then Spark. Java and Scala got installed successful. Spark got installed successfully as well.

When I tried to verify spark installation using below input command, I ran into an error.

**Input command:** `spark-shell`

**Expected Behavior:** Expect Spark to start on terminal

**Actual Behavior:** I get this below error:

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.8".
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.4.5/libexec/jars/spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.5.jar) to method java.nio.Bits.unaligned()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getAuthenticationMethod(SecurityUtil.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:634)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.secMgr$lzycompute$1(SparkSubmit.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$secMgr$1(SparkSubmit.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:356)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:774)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3756)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1902)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:52)
```

**What I tried:**

I tried to change JAVA_HOME using below commands:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/java
```

Previous JAVA_HOME path was `/opt/anaconda3`. I can see that JAVA_HOME got changed to `usr/local/opt/java`.

I am still getting the error. Appreciate your answers/feedback. Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you install a newer version of Java? What is the result of `/usr/local/opt/java/bin/java -version`?

Comment: Yes, as part of spark installation I did install a newer version of Java.  

Strange... ```/usr/local/opt/java/bin/java -version ``` gives me this:   
openjdk version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing). 

and when I just input ```java -version``` from my default prompt, I get this:  

openjdk version "1.8.0_152-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1056-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: Okay. Now try `which java`

Comment: When I try 'which `which java` I am getting this: /Users/skanda_work/opt/anaconda3/bin/java

Comment: `export JAVA_HOME=/Users/skanda_work/opt/anaconda3`

Comment: I would suggest you look at [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/). It makes installing spark a lot easier.

Comment: Tried the export with new path, still getting exact same error. Let me check sdkman as well.

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps for macOS
Step 1. install java 8 as Spark 2.2 onwards requires java8. See [Spark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html)! for details.

> brew install openjdk@8

Then set update java path

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 2):

I was searching across the web and saw instructions to install pyspark.

I ran this command `pip install pyspark` on Terminal

After I installed pyspark, both spark and pyspark are running.

Not sure what happened, but I am able to run spark now.

Thanks @Elliott for interacting and giving some directions!

Comment: Agreed, `pip install` works over `conda install` or [binaries](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-2.4.7/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz) on a MacBook Pro.